# Regex - Extract string between square bracket tag

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I've tags in string like `[note]some text[/note]` where I want to extract the inside text between the tags.

Sample Text:

```
Want to extract data [note]This is the text I want to extract[/note] 
but this is not only tag [note]Another text I want to [text:sample] 
extract[/note]. Can you do it?
```

From the given text, extract following:

`This is the text I want to extract`

`Another text I want to [text:sample] extract`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try matching using the following regex pattern:

```
\[note\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/note\]
```

This says to just capture whatever comes in between `[note]` and the closest closing `[/note]` tag.  Note that we use `[\s\S]*` to potentially match desired content across newlines, should that be necessary.

```js
var re = /\[note\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/note\]/g;
var s = 'Want to extract data [note]This is the text I want to extract[/note]\nbut this is not only tag [note]Another text I want to [text:sample]\n extract[/note]. Can you do it?';
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[1]);
    }
} while (m);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this while Tim posted his answer and it's quite like but I figured I'll post it anyway since it's extracted to a re-usable function you can use for any tag.

```
const str = `Want to extract data [note]This is the text I want to extract[/note] 
but this is not only tag [note]Another text I want to [text:sample] 
extract[/note]. Can you do it?`;

function extractTagContent(tag, str) {
  const re = new RegExp(`\\[${tag}\\](.*?)\\[\\/${tag}\\]`, "igs");
  const matches = [];
  let found;
  while ((found = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    matches.push(found[1]);
  }
  return matches;
}

const content = extractTagContent("note", str);
// content now has:
// ['This is the text I want to extract', 'Another text I want to [text:sample] extract. Can you do it?']
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/kw006560oo